# Is it possible to create temp structs/classes with initializer lists?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

It looks like a very basic question that should have an explicit googlable answer, but I wasn't able to find it so far. It *seems* like the answer is no, but I wanted to make sure.
What I mean is comething like this:

```
struct A { int a,b; };
void foo(const A&); // just some function
foo(A{1,2}); // doesn't work, but it was a long shot
foo(A({1,2})); // looks like it could have worked, but it doesn't
foo(A(std::initializer_list<int>({1,2}))); // ugly and doesn't work either anyway
```

Update:
option 2 actually works (as well as an even a simpler foo({1,2})), but only in vs2013, not in 2012.

Update #2: come on, was it necessary to downvote it so hard? It's still useful to know that it only works starting with vs2013.

Comment: What error is the first two giving?

Comment: Those first two should work fine. This is aggregate initialization. Even `foo({1,2});` should work, I think.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. [mcve] please.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling in C++11 mode?

Comment: @Anton Have you defined `foo` somewhere?

Comment: found out that it only works starting with vs2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even easier than that. Behold the power of uniform initialization:

```
foo({1,2});
```